# Can I perform ANOVA test with time as the dependent variable (y) in R?

Tags: r, datetime, anova, table-statistics

I want to test if the origin of a tadpole affects its metamorphosis date, meaning, if a tadpole's origin is from a pool in the north, would the metamorphosis be earlier than the metamorphosis of a tadpole originated from the south?
to do that, I was hoping to use ANOVA test. my code looks like that:

```
DATE_OF_METAMORPHOSIS -> dmy_hms(DATE_OF_METAMORPHOSIS)

one.way <- aov(DATE_OF_METAMORPHOSIS ~ POPULATION, data = info_table)
```

it did compute something, but I'm not sure how R treated the dates in the DATE_OF_METAMORPHOSIS variable.. if anyone knows if my code did what I've described in words, or knows if R knows how to use dates as a continuance variable and how to do that, I would love the help!
tnx!

example of my data:
info_table

```
ID | POPULATION | DATE_OF_METAMORPHOSIS|
---|------------|----------------------|
1 | 1 | 7/19/2021  12:01:00 AM|
2 | 2 | 7/29/2021  12:01:00 AM|
3 | 3 | 8/1/2021  12:01:00 AM|
4 | 1 | 8/4/2021  12:01:00 AM|
5 | 2 | 5/16/2021  12:01:00 AM|
6 | 3 | 5/14/2021  12:01:00 AM|
```

Comment: Could you please run `dput(info_table)` and edit your question to include the output? That will create a code "recipe" that we can use to make an exact copy of your data with the same data types, which'll make it easier to understand the specifics of your issue and to try out possible solutions.

Comment: Your `DATE_OF_METAMORPHOSIS` variable looks like text that shows dates in "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M%S" format. Your first line assumes a year-month-day order instead of month-day-year, and it does not touch the `info_table` object.

Answer (score 0):

The two errors are:

1. The datetime column is in the format `mdy hms`, not `ymd hms`;
2. There is no column `POPULATION`, it's name is `origin`.

Correct both errors and it's a simple matter of running `aov`.

```r
x <- '
ID | origin | DATE_OF_METAMORPHOSIS|
1 | 1 | 7/19/2021  12:01:00 AM|
2 | 2 | 7/29/2021  12:01:00 AM|
3 | 3 | 8/1/2021  12:01:00 AM|
4 | 1 | 8/4/2021  12:01:00 AM|
5 | 2 | 5/16/2021  12:01:00 AM|
6 | 3 | 5/14/2021  12:01:00 AM|'

info_table <- read.table(textConnection(x), header = TRUE, sep = "|")[-4]
info_table$DATE_OF_METAMORPHOSIS <- lubridate::mdy_hms(info_table$DATE_OF_METAMORPHOSIS)

one.way <- aov(DATE_OF_METAMORPHOSIS ~ origin, data = info_table)
summary(one.way)
#>             Df    Sum Sq   Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
#> origin       1 8.885e+12 8.885e+12   0.743  0.437
#> Residuals    4 4.782e+13 1.196e+13
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: tnx! actually, I put the table as an example but in my data the names and formats match. my question is about how R read the dates and makes statistics out of it...?  like, does it use that as a continuance variable? how does it know? how does it translate the dates to a continuans variable? or does it use it as a categorical variable? (which isnt good for me..)

Comment: @MayaEldar Dates and datetime variables are coded as the number of seconds from an origin, R uses the same origin as unix, 1970-01-01. So they are a continuous variables See also [`?as.POSIXct`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/as.POSIXlt.html) for the origins used by other software programs.